# MS SQL Server 2005 - How to Auto Increment a field (not primary key)

Tags: sql-server

I would like to automatically increment a field named `incrementID' anytime any field in any row within the table named 'tb_users' is updated.
Currently I am doing it via the sql update statement.
i.e "UPDATE tb_users SET name = @name, incrementID = incrementID + 1 .....WHERE id = @id;

I'm wondering how I can do this automatically. for example, by changing the way sql server treats the field - kind of like the increment setting of 'Identity'.
Before I update a row, I wish to check whether the incrementID of the object to be updated is different to the incrementID of the row of the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trigger should do the trick:

```
create trigger update_increment for update as
if not update(incrementID) 
  UPDATE tb_users SET incrementID = incrementID + 1 
    from inserted WHERE tb_users.id = inserted.id
```

Comment: Can you explain what this query does ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Columns in the Table can have an **Identity Specification** set. Simply expand the node in the property window and fill in the details (Is Identity, Increment, Seed).

The **IDENTITYCOL** keyword can be used for operations on Identity Specifications.

Comment: He doesn't want an identity column but a column with incrementing value within one row.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to set this up via EMS SQL manager but keep getting an error message when trying to compile:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tb_users]
ADD [incrementID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NULL
GO
message:
Could not create IDENTITY attribute on nullable column 'incrementID', table 'dbo.tb_users'

Comment: @bazjapan Just remove NULL from your ALTER statement so it will read ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tb_users] ADD [incrementID] int IDENTITY(1, 1)
The identity cannot be NULL

Comment: Try dropping the column and re-adding it as an identity.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger for this (if I've read you correctly and you want the value incremented each time you update the row).

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to know that it changed, rather than specifically that this is a later version or how many changes there have been, consider using a `rowversion` column.