# Entity Framework Core Default Value Not Loading After Add Range

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Net Core 2.0 Entity Framework. When I try to insert data using `_context.UserTask.AddRange(userTasks)`, the `TaskID` is not being updated after invoking `SaveChanges()`. Below is the code I'm using.

```
public partial class UserTask
{
    public Guid TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Text{get;set;}
}

var tasks = taskTexts.Select(s => new UserTask { Text="abc" });

_context.UserTask.AddRange(tasks);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

foreach(var n in notifications){
    n.TaskID //This is not returning the actualID inserted on the DB
}
```

Below is the Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Task(
TaskID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Text] [varchar](200) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TaskID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
TaskID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE  dbo.Task ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TaskID]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) 
FOR [TaskID]
GO
```

Comment: from where `notifications` is coming? and what do you mean by value not being updated?

Comment: Sorry it is not notifications, it is tasks

Comment: value not being updated means, after SaveChangesAsync, if I try to get the TaskID in the foreach loop the value is not same as DB, it is just 0000-0000....

Comment: I got the solution. The problem is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480952/cant-auto-generate-identity-with-addrange-in-entity-framework

Comment: find the reason why is it working and add as answer

Comment: done, thanks @GertArnold

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're adding a new UserTask, I mean you are getting the task range to add by using a Select function and you are not checking the result.
Another thing i don't understand is after call "SaveChanges", you are  loopping over a diferent object (notification object VS userTask object), maybe it's something wrong over there.

Try something like this:

```
        List<UserTask> listToAdd = new List<UserTask>().Add(new UserTask { Text = "NewUserTaskForTest" });

        _context.UserTask.AddRange(tasks);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        foreach (var userTask in _context.UserTask)
        {
            userTask.TaskID;
            Console.WriteLine(userTask.TaskID.ToString());
        }
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks. mistakenly I put the notification there, I got the issue. The fix is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480952/cant-auto-generate-identity-with-addrange-in-entity-framework